# Не отображаются картинки на LIve Server'е

Tags: html, css

Верстаю я сайт по видеоуроку, завершил вёрстку и стилизацию navbar'a, там же есть блок с картинками-ссылками, ведущими на соц. сети компании:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти картинки отображаются на локальном файле, но когда я запускаю Live Server, эти картинки полностью исчезает, да и блок в целом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a class="logo__link" href="#"><i></i> Woodtech <span>Architecture</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-6 col-6 menu-container">
                <i class="menu-toggle"></i>
                <ul class="top-menu">
                    <li class="top-menu__item"><span class="top-menu__link">Главная</span></li>
                    <li class="top-menu__item"><a class="top-menu__link" href="#">Проекты</a></li>
                    <li class="top-menu__item"><a class="top-menu__link" href="#">Услуги</a></li>
                    <li class="top-menu__item"><a class="top-menu__link" href="#">Блог</a></li>
                    <li class="top-menu__item"><a class="top-menu__link" href="#">Компания</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 d-none d-lg-block nav-social-wrap">
                <div class="nav-social">
                    <a class="nav-social__item" target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/fa-soc/white/instagram-brands.svg" alt="Instagram"></a>
                    <a class="nav-social__item" target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/fa-soc/white/vk.svg" alt="VK"></a>
                    <a class="nav-social__item" target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/fa-soc/white/facebook-brands.svg" alt="Facebook"></a>
                    <a class="nav-social__item" target="_blank" href="#"><img src="images/fa-soc/white/twitter-brands.svg" alt="Twitter"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Путь к картинкам указан правильный.

Comment: images  - директория должна находиться рядом с html файлом.

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/hRq26rz/Screenshot-3.png